# Adjusting font size and image in UIWebView iOs

Tags: image, mobile, fonts, uiwebview, scale

I am interested in displaying the following URL in a UIWebView:
https://mlogin.yahoo.com/

The trouble is that this page renders too large on an iPad.

You can try opening the URL in Safari (on an iPad) directly and you will see what I mean.

I want to present the page in a UIWebView so that it looks aesthetically pleasing and not bloated and gigantic.

I tried the following approach (which does help partially)

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wView {
    [wView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '50%'"];
}
```

However, this approach only changes the font size. The images still look fugly.

Anybody got any ideas?

Maybe inserting something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320"/>
```

in the head of the document would help?

If so, can anyone give the code snippet to insert this programmatically (in a similar fashion to changing text size code provided by me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I eventually used the following which achieves my purpose:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wView {
    [wView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '50%'"];
    [wView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zoom= '0.5'"];
}
```